# Adding components to existing Ractive instance

Tags: ractivejs

I have a somewhat weird question.

In Ractive we can do something like this.

**App’s template:**

```
<h1>My app</h1><SubComponent/>
```

And generally have `SubComponent`’s template access data from `App`.

Is there any way to have the same behaviour without mentioning `SubComponent` in the template?

**Something like:**

```
const App = new Ractive({el: ‘#myapp’, …………});
const SubComponent = Ractive.extend({ append: true, ………… });
const example = new SubComponent()
example.render(App.el)
```

But, with `example`’s template being able to access `App`’s data, maybe also giving `App` the chance to find it by using `App.findComponent()`.

What I’m trying to do, is having unpredictable (= I can’t include them inside templates by default) nested components.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work out for you..
But you can just put a div with a known ID in

```
<h1>My app</h1><div id="subcomp" />
```

Then mount your dynamic SubComponent under there. 
You can use can event like oncomplete - which will guarentee than div#subcomp has been added to dom.

```
oncomplete: function() {
   this.mycompRef = new SubComponent( { el: '#subcomp' });
   // You can skip findComponent and use mycompRef
}
```